# Woking with files in relative paths in C# WebApi Projects - Debug and Published

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I´m building a Web Project, and I need some txt files for authentication with Azure

```
string authFile = @"C:\absolutepath\myfile.auth";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_AUTH_LOCATION", authFile);
```

The problem is that absolute path. It will work on Debug mode, in Published only if the paths were the same. I have added those files to my Project, and I can see them in the zip file when I publish the Project.

What is the canonical/better form to make the files available both in Debug and Published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't hardcode your file paths**.

Use configuration files to set the file paths for every system itself.

- [Visual Studio can easily create you config files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx).
- Or create an **optional** config file in your project root directory (i.e.: appsettings.json) and try loading it on startup to initialize your application settings. **But** if your programm does not find this config file it fallbacks to your hardcoded defaults. Remember to set the content type of this project item to 'Content' and the publish action to 'always copy' or 'copy if newer'

This config file may also contain the content from your `myfile.auth` file.

*Remember to properly structure your config file, allowing it to store more than just one information.*

Comment: It doesn´t seem to have this tool on VS 2017

Comment: I'm currently not at my windows machine but you should do it via -> Project (Right Click) -> Properties -> Left panel: Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can include a check for the request type. If local request, use absolute path, otherwise use canonical path.

```
string authFile = "";    
if (Request.IsLocal) {
authFile = @"C:\absolutepath\myfile.auth"; //absolute path;
}
else {
authFile = "server path" //canonical path
}
```